# The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. Help me please

Tags: c#

I want to send an email from my application to verify the email that I used to register but getting this error.

```
The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response 
was: 5.7.57 SMTP;
```

I tried going into my Gmail settings and allow less secure apps On but it still doesn't work.

**UserController.cs**

```
[NonAction]
    public void SendVerificaitonLinkEmail(string email, string activationCode, string emailFor = "VerifyAccount")
    {
        var verifyUrl = "/User/" + emailFor + "/" + activationCode;
        var link = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(Request.Url.PathAndQuery, verifyUrl);

        var fromEmail = new MailAddress("dotnetawesome@gmail.com", "Dotnet Awesome");
        var toEmail = new MailAddress(email);
        var fromEmailPassword = "**********"; // Replace with actual password

        string subject = "";
        string body = "";
        if (emailFor == "VerifyAccount")
        {
            subject = "Your account is successfully created!";

            body = "<br/><br/>We are excited to tell you that your Rockstar Awesome account is" +
                " successfully created. Please click on the below link to verify your account" +
                " <br/><br/><a href ='" + link + "'>" + link + "</a> ";
        }
        else if (emailFor == "ResetPassword")
        {
            subject = "Reset Password";
            body = "Hi, <br/><br/> We got request for reset your account password. Please click on the link below to reset your password." +
                "<br/><br/><a href = " + link + ">Reset Password link </a>";
        }



        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
        {
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromEmail.Address, fromEmailPassword);
        };

        using (var message = new MailMessage(fromEmail, toEmail)
        {
            Subject = subject,
            Body = body,
            IsBodyHtml = true
        })
            client.Send(message); // 
    }
```

Comment: What happens if you try port [465](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-smtp#:~:text=The%20outgoing%20SMTP%20server%2C%20smtp,before%20issuing%20the%20STARTTLS%20command.)?

Comment: I get System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: 'Failure sending mail.'

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using `MailKit` (https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) - the code is better maintained, easier to use and the author actually responds to issues on the github. The built in .net `SmtpClient` is not maintained anymore.

Not saying this will fix your issue, but it's worth a try - there is an smtp client that you can connect with, then call authenticate and finally start sending messages with, making it easier to identify points of failure.

Example with `MailKit`:

```cs
var message = new MimeKit.MimeMessage();
message.From.Add(new MimeKit.MailboxAddress("Name From", "YOU_FROM_ADDRESS@gmail.com"));
message.To.Add(new MimeKit.MailboxAddress("Name To", "YOU_TO_ADDRESS@gmail.com"));
message.Subject = "Subject Line";

message.Body = new MimeKit.TextPart("plain")
{
    Text = @"Mail body message"
};

using var client = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient();
client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
client.Authenticate("YOUR_GMAIL_NAME", "YOUR_PASSWORD");
client.Send(message);
client.Disconnect(true);
```

Comment: I get CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'MimeKiet.MimeMessage' to 'System.Net.Mail.MailMessage'

Comment: Updated the answer to use full namespaces, that should help

Comment: Thank you this worked! I gave an upvote but I have less than 15 reputation so it's not public. Now I need to figure out how to get the verification link inside the email. Do I still need to allow less secure apps through gmail settings?

Comment: You could always try that and see if it works :)